# How to force convert json action in Cakephp Rest

Tags: json, rest, cakephp

i need force convert json action in cakephp rest response. When i set '_serialize' like this

```
$this->set(array('message' => $lessons, '_serialize' => array('message')));
```

it works but some turkish characters view in unicode like "\u00e7al\u0131\u015fma alan\u0131".

It's solution is render data with `json_encode($data,  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` but cakephp render it automatically. How to force json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ?

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2):

in cakePHP 3 you can say in controller:

```
$this->set('_jsonOptions', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$this->set('_serialize', ['zones']);
```

which will override the options used.

Answer (score 1):

## JsonView doesn't accept options

There's no way to inject options in the `json_encode()` call invoked by `JsonView`, as it's hard coded optionless in the `_serialize()` method like this:

```
protected function _serialize($serialize) {
    // ...

    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>=') && Configure::read('debug')) {
        return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

## Use a custom/extended view

So if you want to use automatic serialization, then you have to create your own/an extended view that either accepts options, or hard codes your desired options.

Here's an (untested) example with hard coded options. The `_serialize()` method is basically just a copy with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option added:

```
App::uses('JsonView', 'View');

class MyJsonView extends JsonView {
    protected function _serialize($serialize) {
        if (is_array($serialize)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($serialize as $alias => $key) {
                if (is_numeric($alias)) {
                    $alias = $key;
                }
                if (array_key_exists($key, $this->viewVars)) {
                    $data[$alias] = $this->viewVars[$key];
                }
            }
            $data = !empty($data) ? $data : null;
        } else {
            $data = isset($this->viewVars[$serialize]) ? $this->viewVars[$serialize] : null;
        }

        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>=') && Configure::read('debug')) {
            return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }

        return json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#creating-your-own-view-classes**

Answer (score 1):

*I haven't tested this myself, so it's just from the top of my head.*

You could write your own View class extending `JsonView` and override the `_serialize` method.
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4e8e266754a25748f481b2f567e45f767808be53/lib/Cake/View/JsonView.php#L131

```
<?php
App::uses('JsonView', 'View');

class MyCustomView extends JsonView {

    protected function _serialize($serialize) {
        if (is_array($serialize)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($serialize as $alias => $key) {
                if (is_numeric($alias)) {
                    $alias = $key;
                }
                if (array_key_exists($key, $this->viewVars)) {
                    $data[$alias] = $this->viewVars[$key];
                }
            }
            $data = !empty($data) ? $data : null;
        } else {
            $data = isset($this->viewVars[$serialize]) ? $this->viewVars[$serialize] : null;
        }

        return json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

And then in your controller do something like

```
<?php

App::uses('MyCustomView', 'View');

class SomeController extends AppController {

    public function someMethod() {
        $this->viewClass = 'MyCustomView';

        // What ever you normally do
    }
}
```